# TikZ, 3D multiple layers with orthogonal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

Using the Ti*k*Z 3D library, I would like to reproduce the following image:

[image]

Some details:

- the planes have an arbitrary angle;
- they are parallel and opaque;
- the arrow segment is orthogonal to the plane surfaces.

I only found examples with single figures, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320782/3d-projection-on-a-line-in-tikz-3d) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz), but they didn't help here. What could be the correct approach to realize the above image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You can adjust the rotation angle(s) in `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{0}` to your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{0}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\foreach \Z in {1,2,3,4}
{
\draw[fill=blue] (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,-3,\Z) -- cycle;
}
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,7);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```