# Tikz drawing problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw two planes one above the other and a diagonal above them. Currently, I am even unable to draw the two planes one above the other. Here is what I'm doing

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \tikz
    % plane
    \draw (0,0) -- ++ (45:2.2) -- ++ (3.3,0) -- ++ (225:2.2) -- cycle;  
    \draw (50,0) -- ++ (45:52.2) -- ++ (3.3,50) -- ++ (225:52.2) -- cycle;  
\end{figure}
```

If I remove the second line it works and draws a plane, but for some reason with the second line it says "command draw undefined" although it doesn't have the same problem on the first line.

Comment: Either use `{` and `}` around the draw commands work with the `tikzpicture` environment. `\tikz{
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (45:2.2) -- ++ (3.3,0) -- ++ (225:2.2) -- cycle;  
\draw (50,0) -- ++ (45:52.2) -- ++ (3.3,50) -- ++ (225:52.2) -- cycle; }` The coordinates `50` and `52.2` seem also unusually large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% plane
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (45:2.2) -- ++ (3.3,0) -- ++ (225:2.2) -- cycle;
\draw (0,-1) -- ++ (45:2.2)  -- ++ (3.3,0)  -- ++ (225:2.2) -- cycle;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: It helped a lot! Thanks. I'm still new to this.

Comment: @KostasPsaromiligkos You may also look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425806/121799), if you want...